# Arranging 4 divs parallel vertically using html css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying since 4 hours to arrange 4 div side by side vertically.Those div are also having 2 div inside it,for image and paragraph.I'm able to arrange the 4 image div next to each other but paragraph div is difficult to align.

Code I'm using:

```css
.left4 {
  width: 215px;
  float: left;
}
.center4 {
  float: left;
  width: 215px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.center4.1 {
  width: 215px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.right4 {
  width: 215px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.image4 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 215px;
  border: 4px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: #BABABA;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.para1 {
  height: 200px;
  color: #BABABA;
}
```

```html
<div class="4">
  <div class="left4">
    <div class="image4">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="para1">
      <h3 style="color:#BABABA">INDONECTETUS FACILIS</h3>
      <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
      <p align="right"><a href="#" style="color:orange;text-decoration:none">Read More >></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center4">
    <div class="image4">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="para1">
      <h3 style="color:#BABABA">INDONECTETUS FACILIS</h3>
      <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
      <p align="right"><a href="#" style="color:orange;text-decoration:none">Read More >></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="center4.1">
    <div class="image4">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="para1">
      <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
      <p align="right"><a href="#" style="color:orange;text-decoration:none">Read More >></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="right4">
    <div class="image4">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="para1">
      <h3 style="color:#BABABA">INDONECTETUS FACILIS</h3>
      <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: will you post the output image ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `.center4.1`. In CSS, It means you are trying to access multiple classes `center4` and `1`. Change it to `.center4-1`

```css
.left4 {
   width: 215px;
   float: left;
 }
 .center4 {
   float: left;
   width: 215px;
   padding-right: 50px;
   padding-left: 50px;
 }
 .center4-1 {
   width: 215px;
   float: right;
   padding-left: 10px;
   float: left;
 }
 .right4 {
   width: 215px;
   float: left;
   padding-left: 40px;
 }
 .image4 {
   height: 100px;
   width: 215px;
   border: 4px;
   border-style: double;
   border-color: #BABABA;
   float: left;
   margin-top: 10px;
 }
 .para1 {
   height: 200px;
   color: #BABABA;
 }
```

```html
<div class="4">
  <div class="left4">
    <div class="image4">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="para1">
      <h3 style="color:#BABABA">INDONECTETUS FACILIS</h3>
      <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
      <p align="right"><a href="#" style="color:orange;text-decoration:none">Read More >></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center4">
    <div class="image4">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="para1">
      <h3 style="color:#BABABA">INDONECTETUS FACILIS</h3>
      <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
      <p align="right"><a href="#" style="color:orange;text-decoration:none">Read More >></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="center4-1">
    <div class="image4">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="para1">
      <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
      <p align="right"><a href="#" style="color:orange;text-decoration:none">Read More >></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="right4">
    <div class="image4">
      <img>
    </div>
    <div class="para1">
      <h3 style="color:#BABABA">INDONECTETUS FACILIS</h3>
      <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I puuting some basic concept how you can do this.It will work in all size

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .box {
        background-color: coral;
        width: 30%;
        display:inline-block;
        margin:10px 0;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
    .text {
        padding: 10px 0;
        color:white;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

With "display: flex;" you have a easy way to wrap
[Flex How?](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**CSS**

```
    .container{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.box{
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #BABABA;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.text{
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
    <div class="img">

    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h3 style="color:#BABABA">INDONECTETUS FACILIS</h3>
        <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
        <p align="right"><a href="#" style="color:orange;text-decoration:none">Read More >></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="img">

    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h3 style="color:#BABABA">INDONECTETUS FACILIS</h3>
        <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
        <p align="right"><a href="#" style="color:orange;text-decoration:none">Read More >></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="img">

    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h3 style="color:#BABABA">INDONECTETUS FACILIS</h3>
        <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
        <p align="right"><a href="#" style="color:orange;text-decoration:none">Read More >></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="img">

    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h3 style="color:#BABABA">INDONECTETUS FACILIS</h3>
        <p>Some wiki engines are open source, whereas others are proprietary. Some permit control over different functions (levels of access)</p>
        <p align="right"><a href="#" style="color:orange;text-decoration:none">Read More >></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no problem :) I really recommend to have a look at Flex too

Comment: sure.I will try that too.